# Pass value to apex controller using apex action support

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, actionsupport

Im trying to pass values to apex controller from vf page but values are not passing.
could you guys please check where im going wrong.

VF PAGE

```
<apex:repeat value="{!am.names}" var="n"> 
        <td> 
          <input type="radio" name="name"  value="{!n}"/> 
          <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!getSelectedInfo}">
              <apex:param assignTo="{!checkedname}" name="checkedname" value="{!n}" />
          </apex:actionsupport>
          {!n} 
       </td>
</apex:repeat>
```

APEX Controller:

```
public static string checkedname{get;set;}    
public void getSelectedInfo(){
    system.debug('Selected name  '+checkedname);
}
```

Comment: It is likely because the variable `checkedname` is a static variable.

Comment: instead of using `<input ...>`, use an `apex:inputText`, styled as a radio